# How to create IPython/Jupyter kernel with custom python environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, virtualenv

I have a virtual environment containing a package I need to test in a notebook.

I've got it working in the following manner:

```
> pip install ipykernel

> ipython kernel install --user --name=foo
Installed kernelspec foo in /Users/pi/Library/Jupyter/kernels/foo

> cat /Users/pi/Library/Jupyter/kernels/foo/kernel.json
{
 "argv": [
  "/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "foo",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Now I edit the python path in that file to `/path/to/my/virtualenv/bin/python`.

Now I do `jupyter notebook` -> new -> foo, and create a test-cell with `import MyPackage`, and it works!

My question is: is there a proper way to do this?

(Useful link: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use [`pipenv`](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv).

First create a new folder and `cd` to it:

```
mkdir [name-of-my-python-env]
cd [name-of-my-python-env]
```

Now install the environment along with any additional packages you need:

```
pipenv install jupyter foo bar
```

Start the notebook server:

```
pipenv run jupyter notebook
```

If you need to add any new dependencies just `pipenv install` them and restart your server.